# UIKit Particle Systems with Open GL ES?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, particles, glkit

I am making an iOS game using Open GL ES 2.0 and GLKit. Is it possible to use the new iOS 5 UIKit Particle Systems with it? Or am I better off just making my own particle system?

Comment: did you implement the particle designer inside glkitview? please post your code here. thnx!

Answer (score 0):

If your game is based on [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org), you can use it's particle system.
Otherwise you can still take a look on how the particle system is implemented by cocos2d 2.x which uses OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

In UIKit you create particle systems by using the QuartzCore framework. For a complete example check out this article:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial